# Cannot send a simple HTTPS Request in Android (Volley)

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

Background: I am trying to do a request to a HTTPS API to ask if a client is already registered.
Question: Why does the RequestQueue never work?

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                System.out.println("ggg:"+response);
                if (response.contains("HERE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImportContactsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                } else if (response.contains("OK")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (response.contains("logoff")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please log off your old device to login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //sSystem.out.println("bla: "+error);
    }
});
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

> Also I tested the same URL in my Browser and it takes less than a second to get the response.

Comment: Have you requested for the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @StuStirling Yes because I have other parts that use HTTPS that work.

Comment: Ok, that would have been too easy I guess. I suppose you're also not getting an error from Volley? Can you see the network request go to the API via Charles or the Android Profiler/

Comment: Make sure request method is right. i.e. GET

Comment: can you add your response in question?